# Samsung Galaxy Y (Android 2.3) Ctrl+Z error in SMS command with serial port

Tags: android, sms, serial-port, gsm

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Y cellphone like a GSM-SMS modem via Serial COM, all is OK but when I have finished the commands:

AT+CMGS="12017572673"

> Message Text.

And when I try to send Ctrl + Z, I received this error:

> +CME ERROR: 513

The same software works with other phones but this issue is only with Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Sumsung Galaxy 2 GT IP1000P. I could communicate with the phone using AT commands such ATI AT+CMGF AT+CPIN AT+CMEE. It would even accept the AT+CMGS command upto the point of sending ctrl+Z where I go CMS 303 error (operation not allowed).
I contacted Samsung support and was told that the phone could not be used this way. Whether this is an android defect/bug/policy, or a deliberate inadequacy by Samsung, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error when the phone is busy doing something and not ready to receive commands from minicom, so what I do I restart the phone while leaving the usb cable connected, this worked for me